# Robot Framework "Select From List" command error

Tags: robotframework

I am trying to choose a option by  Robot Framework native Keyword "Select From List" command, however it is failed with error message :

html page source:

```
<select id="reason" placeholder="Please select" style="width: 100%; display: none;" class="m-b-xs" data-role="combobox" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false">
<option value="a">Assume</option>
<option value="b">New</option>
<option value="c">Renew</option>
<option value="d">Purchase</option>
<option value="e">Refinance</option>
<option value="f">Reschedul</option>
<option selected="selected" value="New">New</option>
</select>
```

I used value "Assume" or "a":

```
Choose Application Reason
    Select From List    xpath=//select[@id="reason"]    Assume
```

Test was failed with error message:

```
INFO : Selecting option(s) 'Assume' from list
'xpath=//select[@id="reason"]'.  
.....
FAIL :ValueError: Option 'Assume' not in list 'xpath=//select[@id="reason"]'.
INFO : Selecting option(s) 'a' from list 'xpath=//select[@id="reason"]'.
.....
FAIL : ValueError: Option 'a' not in list 'xpath=//select[@id="reason"]'.
```

But if I replace value "Assume" with default vale "New":

```
Choose Application Reason
    Select From List    xpath=//select[@id="reason"]    New
```

test was passed.

Can anyone do the help? Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 5):

I had similar issues with select drop downs and i tried this and worked for me.

```
click element   xpath=//select[@id="reason"]
wait until element is visible   xpath=//option[contains(text(),'${label}')]
click element   xpath=//option[contains(text(),'${label}')]
```

If you want to select any static value form the list.

```
click element   xpath=//select[@id="reason"]
click element   xpath=//select/option[0]
```

You can also use text equal,

```
click element   xpath=//option[text()='${label}')]
```

To ignore blank,

```
click element   xpath=//option[normalize-space(text())='Assume']
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess it worked as New is a default option. 
For me keyword "Select from List by Value" works better.
Try:

```
Select From List by Value    xpath=//select[@id="reason"]    a
```

If it doesn't work - I used to have an error with an element state - add Click Element before selecting from list:

```
Click Element    xpath=//select[@id="reason"]
Select From List by Value    xpath=//select[@id="reason"]    a
```

Answer (score 1):

Other alternative by using `Index`

```
Select From List By Index    xpath=//select[@id="reason"]    1
```

Answer (score 1):

when you want to value `a`,
I solved the problem this way.

`***Keywords***`

```
Select By Value

   [Arguments]    ${locator}    ${value}

   Page Should Contain Element    ${locator}  10

   Select From List By Value      ${locator}  ${value}

   List Selection Should Be       ${locator}  ${value}
```

Active time,

`***Test Case ***`

```
Choose Application Reason
    Select By Value  reason  a
```

Answer (score 0):

should use Label, which means text

e.g.

```
Select From List By Label   xpath=//select[@id="reason"]    Assume
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should select by value :

```
select from list by value       xpath=//select[@id="reason"]     a
```